# (Java) Strings separated by whitespace from list

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a String ArrayList that contains:
[﻿3 9 12, 6 6 12, 36 12 48, 1 1 2, 1 2 3, 8 10 18, 5 12 17, 77 5 82, 32 2 34, 92 15 107, 99 6 105]

Each String contains three integers. How can I separate those integers separated by whitespace and add them to three different ArrayLists so they look like this:

list1 :[3, 6, 36, 1, 1, 8, 5, 77, 32, 92, 99]

list2: [9, 6, 12, 1, 2, 10, 12, 5, 2, 15, 6]

list3: [12, 12, 48, 2, 3, 18, 17, 82, 34, 107, 105]

And the three resulting lists would still be of type String. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with String#split ?

Comment: what did you try to achive this? did you google it at least?

Comment: Consider adding code-tags around your lists, for better readability.

Comment: @KevinEsche yes I did and one the things I tried was line.split("\\s*") and different regex values but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a single element of the String ArrayList `3 9 12` and then split it into it's own string array with `split`

```
ArrayList<String> arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // for the 1st num in each pair of 3
ArrayList<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // for the 2nd num in each pair of 3
ArrayList<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // for the 3rd num in each pair of 3


// then loop this part below for however many elements are in the original ArrayList "list"
String str = list.get(0); // assuming index 0 was "3 9 12"
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
arrList1.add(arr[0]);
arrList2.add(arr[1]);
arrList3.add(arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your ArrayList and then use String.split() to seperate your values.

```
for(String values : yourArrayList){
    String[] parts = values.split(" ");
    youNewArrayList1.add(parts[0]);
    youNewArrayList2.add(parts[1]);
    youNewArrayList3.add(parts[2]);
}
```